# Update like count span in same duplicate post

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have a duplicate list of posts on the same page. Hence, some posts appear on the same page more than once.

The like system updates through javascript the like count of a post in a span, with id "like-{{ $item->id }}", it is identified with the post id.

```
<span id="like-{{ $item->id }}">
    @json($item->likers()->count())
</span>
```

When a post is liked, only one post card is updated, the others are not, despite having the same id.

How can I solve this annoyance?

```js
function likePost(a) {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content")
    }
  });
  $(this);
  $.ajax({
    url: APP_URL + "/save_like",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      item: a,
      _token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content")
    },
    success: function(e) {
      var t;
      1 == e.bool ? ($("#like-icon-" + a).removeClass("text-muted").addClass("icon-filled text-danger"), t = $("#like-" + a).text(), $("#like-" + a).text(++t)) : 0 == e.bool && ($("#like-icon-" + a).removeClass("icon-filled text-danger").addClass("text-muted"), t = $("#like-" + a).text(), $("#like-" + a).text(--t))
    },
    error: function(e) {
      location.replace(APP_URL + "/login")
    }
  })
};
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="likePost({{ $item->id }})" class="btn btn-light border-0"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="like-icon-{{ $item->id }}" class="icon @if(Auth::check()) @if(Auth::user()->hasLiked($item)) icon-filled text-danger @else text-muted @endif @else text-muted @endif" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M19.5 13.572l-7.5 7.428l-7.5 -7.428m0 0a5 5 0 1 1 7.5 -6.566a5 5 0 1 1 7.5 6.572" /></svg> <span id="like-{{ $item->id }}">@json($item->likers()->count())</span></a>
```

---

Changes applied:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-light border-0">
     <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="like-icon-{{ $item->id }}" class="icon  icon-filled text-danger" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M19.5 13.572l-7.5 7.428l-7.5 -7.428m0 0a5 5 0 1 1 7.5 -6.566a5 5 0 1 1 7.5 6.572" /></svg> 
     <span id="like-{{ $item->id }}">
          @json($item->likers()->count())
     </span>
</a>
```

And the java code you provided.
It shows no errors, but it doesn't work.

---

In order not to be fully explained in my intent, I leave some pictures on my problem.

I have a tab that fetches all the categories and posts within them, consequently some posts are duplicated, but by clicking like the first of the posts is updated (the like count) while in the other cards it is not.

[image]

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: IDs in JavaScript must be unique. Give them the same class if you want to access more than one item

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately I am not very experienced, so should I also create an identifying class in the span in addition to the id?

Comment: Yes. for example `<span class="likeSpan" data-id="{{ $item->id }}">`

Comment: Please post RENDERED HTML and Script. Click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve] IN YOUR QUESTION

Comment: Using your example, how should I modify the javascript code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

1. change `<span id="like-{{ $item->id }}">` to
   `<span class="likes" data-id="{{ $item->id }}">`
2. Change the link code to this - Add the ID to the link and not to the SVG or span

```
<a href="#"  id="like-{{ $item->id }}" class="like-link btn btn-light border-0">
  <svg ... /></svg> <span>1 like</span>
</a>
```

```js
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content")
  }
});

$("a[id^=like]").on("click", function() {
  const $link = $(this);
  const a = $link.attr("id").split("-")[1]; // make id="like-1234" into 1234
  console.log(a)
  
  /* Commented to test this snippet. uncomment in working code
  
  $.ajax({
    url: APP_URL + "/save_like",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      item: a,
      _token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content")
    },
    success: function(e) {
      const liked = e.bool == 1;
      */
      const liked = 1; // test, remove when using ajax
      $(".likes[data-id="+a+"]").each(function() {
        $(this)
          .toggleClass("text-muted", !liked)
          .toggleClass("icon-filled text-danger", liked)
        let t = +$(this).text();
        t += liked ? 1 : -1
        if (t<0) t=0; // remove if you support negative likes
        $link.find("span").text(t);
        $(this).html($link.html());

      })
    /* },
    error: function(e) {
      location.replace(APP_URL + "/login")
    }
  }) */
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="likes" data-id="1234">
        1
    </span><br/>
<span class="likes" data-id="1234">
        1
    </span>
<hr>


<a href="#" id="like-1234" class="like-link btn btn-light border-0"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon  icon-filled text-danger" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M19.5 13.572l-7.5 7.428l-7.5 -7.428m0 0a5 5 0 1 1 7.5 -6.566a5 5 0 1 1 7.5 6.572" /></svg> <span>1</span></a>
```

Comment: It doesn't generate any errors but it doesn't work, I'm updating the main post with what I did.

Comment: It is hard for me to test your CS in a snippet

Comment: I updated the post with an explanation of my problem through images, maybe I didn't explain myself well. Thank you

Comment: See update. Add the ID to the link and not to the SVG or span

Comment: I have a bit of confusion about the span (the like count) in one part you say to change it as in example 1, but then in the link part it is stripped of every id and class. In the cards I only have the part of the link with its span that counts the likes ... do I have to put the class and data-id there? PS: the like count should increase

Comment: `$(".likes[data-id="+a+"]").each(function() {`

Comment: What I would like is that in the same duplicate posts if clicked I like the update of the like count and red heart will be updated SIMULTANEOUSLY.

Comment: I updated my code. I had a const t instead of a let t

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it works, but I find inconsistencies, for example by clicking several times it increases to infinity (Instead of removing the like), moreover precisely if I try to remove the like it removes it but still increases the count.

Comment: That is my snippet that just counts up. Your code should react to the e.bool. I assumed you could have more than one person liking it - which is why I expected the server to return number of likes instead of 0 or 1

Comment: Your question is how to update more than one at the same time and I answered that

Comment: I've seen now, sorry, great everything works, I was just wondering how to make the red heart appear, instead of the text

Comment: See updated code. I copy the html to the span from the link

Comment: Immediately after clicking, the icon disappears. I checked the code and the red text and filled icon are inserted correctly. I thought it was a button class problem, but still, it seems to disappear. I updated the first post with a screenshot

Comment: I thought the class change would be what you used to set the icon  .toggleClass("text-muted", !liked)
          .toggleClass("icon-filled text-danger", liked)

Comment: The logic is all there. Just change this as needed.  the $(this) is the target span `$(".likes[data-id="+a+"]").each(function() {
        $(this)
          .toggleClass("text-muted", !liked)
          .toggleClass("icon-filled text-danger", liked)
        let t = +$(this).text();
        t += liked ? 1 : -1
        if (t<0) t=0; // remove if you support negative likes
        $link.find("span").text(t);
        $(this).html($link.html());

      })`

Comment: It works, but another problem has arisen, I have updated the first post. In the first post ok, but going to the duplicate post it happens as in the example images. Furthermore, clicking several times displays "NaN"

Comment: You need to separate the number from whatever else is in there. Sorry. Your questions and problems are solvable by you if you consider what you are doing

Answer (score 0):

Need more info.
How are you updating through JavaScript?

If you're using getElementById or so, the problem here is it only returns the first element that satisfies the query not all the elements with the same id on the page. Use a class, that way you can use querySelectorAll and loop through it and do the necessary updates.

HTML:

```
<span id="like-{{ $item->id }}" class="post-{{ $item->id }}">
    @json($item->likers()->count())
</span>
```

JS:

```
const setLikes = postID => {
  const postElems = document.querySelectorAll(`.post-${postID}`);
  // loop through all the posts
  for(let i = 0; i < postElems.length; i++){
    // use the logic here to update the like counts as you want
  }


}
```